# Can we update status according to other status using query

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a database where we have lots of status under array

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("584961127ac6f64c398b456a"),
"ProductList": [{
    "_id": "584961127ac6f64c398b4567",
    "status": "pending"
}, {
    "_id": "584961127ac6f64c398b4567",
    "status": "ready"
}, {
    "_id": "584961127ac6f64c398b4567",
    "status": "accepted"
}, {
    "_id": "584961127ac6f64c398b4567",
    "status": "delivered"
}, ],
"current_status" : "pending",
}
```

I want to change current_status if any status have "pending" status then current_status should be "pending", if any status have "accepted" then current_status should be "accepted".

Note: current_status should be change according to priority "pending","ready","accepted" and  "delivered".

Thanks